# How to get an array from a saved custom field

Tags: php, wordpress

I save my array of integers in a custom fields with the function:

```
update_post_meta($post->ID, "images", array(1, 2, 50));
```

How can I load this array now?

I try to use something like this, but without any luck:

```
global $post;
$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$myarray = $custom["images"][0];
echo $custom["images"];
```

It returns something like `a:3:{i:0;s:1:"1";i:1;s:1:"2";i:2;s:2:"50";}`

May be I can parse this string to get an array from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May be I can parse this string to get an array from this?

This is a [serialized array](http://php.net/serialize).

Use [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/unserialize) to unpack it.